# Loading Windows Form before Showing

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Parent Windows Form from which there are multiple Child forms. Almost every single one of these has the same background image, the parent is a `MDIContainer`.

It is working properly, my problem is that when I call the `Form.Show()` method, after selecting a `MenuStrip` item for a child Form, the form is already showing WHILE the background image is being set.
I think this would be solved by first loading the `BackgroundImage` and then, after a while, showing the form itself.

Any possible advice? Thanks in advance

Comment: Not clear what the actual problem is here. Just timing? Or is the wrong bg showing?

Comment: It is indeed timing, I access the form with .Show(), so the Form is shown and then sets the imagebackground, sets the couple controls and labels... so for 0.5 seconds it looks like the form is going through changes and it looks very poor.

Comment: Find out what part is so slow. Normally this should be instanteneous.

Answer (score 0):

Best fix I think would be to set the right background image for each child form at design time and simply call`. show` to display the form..

Answer (score 0):

Setting BackgroundImageLayout to ImageLayout.Stretch seems to ease the transition, however it still looks a bit odd. I'll keep trying stuff